# How to switch between accounts to check Approve functionality on truffle CLI

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, blockchain, transactions

I am cloning myself of the Openzeppline for my own NFT marketplace.
Mint, enumeration, transferFrom, approve functionalities have been implemented but I have no idea of testing approve functionality with truffle CLI.
I minted 5 NFT tokens on the account 1 from ganache and tried to approve for account 2 to transfer one NFT from account 1 to account 3. So how should I switch from account 1 to account 2 to execute transferFrom on account 2?
I will appreciate it if you give me the solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling a function, for example; `mint(to, amount)`

And you want to call it from another account in truffle you just write:

```
Contract.mint("some address", "amount", {from: accounts[1]})
```

This only works if your truffle console is connected to ganache-cli.

This link might help too. If you aim to write tests.
https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript/